# Allow repeated values in react-select creatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using creatable component from the lib 'react-select'. But i need it to allow repeated values, i've tried setting the prop "isValidNewOption" to always true when i have a valid input. But it still won't allow repeated values. I have a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-antonelli-5s93o?file=/src/App.js). i appreciate the attention, thank you.